# Recursive partial local variables are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I'm using the `ancestry` gem to create nested comments.

In the related Railscasts episode, he uses a helper method which uses a lot of `content_tag`'s... but my partial is quite complex and I don't want to do it that way (I want it in embedded ruby).

The problem is that when a partial is being rendered recursively, the local variables are not being passed.

Initial rendering of comments (where the recursion starts):

```
def index
  @comments = @commentable.comments.includes(:user).arrange(order: :created_at)
  render partial: 'shared/comments', locals: { comments: @comments }
end
```

That creates a hash of nested objects. From there, the partial should take over:

```
<% comments.each do |comment, child_comments| %>
  <div class="comment" data-id="<%= comment.id %>">
    <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar_url, class: 'avatar', size: '40x40' %>
    <div class="content">
        <%= simple_format h(comment.body) %>
      <!-- binding.pry -->
      <%= render('shared/comments', locals: { comments: child_comments }) if child_comments %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I run this I get `undefined local variable or method 'comments'` referencing line 1 of the partial above. This only happens on the recursive 2nd loop though (and I assume any beyond that), the initial loop works fine.

I know the variables are correct because immediately before the render call you will see I put `<!-- binding.pry -->`. If I use pry there I can see that `comments` do indeed have the proper values.

I'm not sure what to do here... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do:

```
<%= render( partial: 'shared/comments', locals: { comments: child_comments }) if child_comments %>
```

Or:

```
<%= render('shared/comments', comments: child_comments) if child_comments %>
```

Comment: err.. that fixed it. it was because I didn't put `partial:`?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as to why? or what magic is going on? Please

Comment: Sorry........ that was dumb. For some reason I was thinking you didn't have to put `partial:`.. although now looking at all my code.. i never wrote that. I'm not sure what i was thinking

Comment: The methods have different signatures, that's all. The second one is a shortcut of the first.